# Ionic 3 : Configure project fail with github

Tags: git, github, ionic3

I try to start a new Ionic 3 project with the new dashboard. I do this :

1. Start my project with sudo ionic start MyApp
2. I link my project to the dashboard

   sudo ionic link
   ✔ Looking up your apps - done!

   ? Which app would you like to link Create a new app

   ? Please enter a name for your new app: MyApp

   > ionic config set app_id (myIdentifier)
   >   [OK] app_id set to "(myIdentifier)" in ./ionic.config.json!
   >   ionic git remote
   >   git remote add ionic git@git.ionicjs.com:vpivet/myapp.git
   >   [OK] Added remote ionic.
   >   [OK] Project linked with app (myIdentifier)!

I tried to continue the setup and run this command :

```
git push ionic master
```

I have this error in my terminal :

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>        Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I don't know what I have to do to have the correct access right. 
What can I do to solve that ?

Comment: you configured with Ionic App Dashboard. Did you set it up with your github repo?

Comment: No I haven't. I don't know how to setup it to connect with dashboard ?

Comment: `sudo ionic link` sets up with Ionic Dashboard not github...

Comment: So I do this yes. But know I have to run sudo git push ionic master. My error is here.

Comment: yup.. http://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/getting-started.html#linking-an-existing-app

Comment: you need to do something like https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/102854243cd066f8b88e

Comment: So I have to create a git repo ? I did it, follow the gist.github tutorial but I keep error with the git push ionic master command ..

Comment: well.. yes if you plan on `git push ionic master` pushing to github.. maybe go through their official docs of using github before proceeding

Answer (score 0):

Run the command with Administrator rights. 'Sudo' (Linux) or 'Run as Administrator' (Windows).